# How to disable key bindings in X3DOM

Tags: javascript, x3dom

I am using X3DOM for a simple game, but I can't use keyboard keys the way I want to, because X3DOM reacts to them.

Example:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', event => this.onKeyDown(event));
```

I want to have my own key event for `if keyCode == 68`. That works, but X3DOM reacts to it too, by changing the navigation mode and displaying an overlay.

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 2):

*disclaimer*: I've never used x3dom, I was just poking around in the source code

there appears to be some code which [disables `keypress` handling](https://github.com/x3dom/x3dom/blob/57bbd8ade9d97aabd9550976973e8cb459aebc33/src/X3DCanvas.js#L158)

```
this.disableKeys = x3dElem.getAttribute("keysEnabled");
this.disableKeys = this.disableKeys ? (this.disableKeys.toLowerCase() == "true") : false;
```

which is later read when setting up the [`keypress` event handler](https://github.com/x3dom/x3dom/blob/57bbd8ade9d97aabd9550976973e8cb459aebc33/src/X3DCanvas.js#L310-L316):

```
this.onKeyPress = function (evt) {
    if (!this.parent.disableKeys) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        this.parent.doc.onKeyPress(evt.charCode);
    }
    this.parent.doc.needRender = true;
}
```

So it appears setting `keysEnabled=...` attribute can turn this off.  The oddity appears to be that their logic is backwards (?) for the condition:

- `x3dElem.getAttribute("keysEnabled")` must be truthy (that is, it must have an attribute)
- if that is falsey, `this.disableKeys` is always false
- otherwise it is equal to that attribute's value lower-cased being equal to `'true'`

So to disable keypress events, use `<... keysEnabled="true" ...>`

I made a [github issue](https://github.com/x3dom/x3dom/issues/934) about the backwards logic, perhaps in the future it will be `keysDisabled="true"` instead

### update:

in the latest version the attribute has been renamed to `disableKeys` so use `<... disableKeys="true" ...>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent X3DOM from reacting to that key:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    if ((event.which === 68) || (event.keyCode === 68)){
        event.preventDefault();
        //
        // ...
        //
    }
});
```

Comment: this only works if you're able to hook into this before loading x3dom -- otherwise due to event handler ordering this is too late